# How to import Scene Builder .fxml file into new NetBeans Java FX desktop project (OSX)

Tags: javafx, netbeans, desktop-application, scenebuilder

I'm new to SceneBuilder and have not used NetBeans much.  I installed NetBeans and SceneBuilder a couple of days ago and created the GUI I want using SceneBuilder but don't know how to start a project in NetBeans and include the .fxml file.  How is that done?

Comment: `File->New Project->JavaFX->JavaFX FXML Application->Finish`

Comment: Depends on the project type. In standard projects you add the resource to the source packages directly, a maven project contains a `Other Sources` package where resources should be added...

Comment: Thanks, I copied it into the source folder.